# Entity Framework Core odd loss of navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm writing a site which uses Entity Framework Core on top of ASP.NET Core. I have a custom `IQueryable` implementation to help with pageable/sortable tables. One of the functions of this custom `IQueryable` is a method called `WithIndices` that creates a tuple for each item, pairing it with its index in the overall dataset (not just the index on that page).

The implementation is as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<(int, TData)> WithIndices()
{
    int i = this.StartIndex;

    foreach (TData item in this.inner)
        yield return (i++, item);
}
```

I'm having an odd loss of data when `TData` is one of my standard models called `Forum`. `Forum` has a property

```
public Forum Parent { get; set; }
```

along with

```
public int? ParentId { get; set; }
```

If I sort my data a particular way, it works. But if I sort it in reverse order (ascending vs descending), the `Parent` property is somehow set to null during the `foreach`.

If I put a breakpoint on the `yield return` line for the misbehaving item, I can inspect `this.inner` and enumerate the Results View in the debugger, causing it to evaluate the query and show the items. The `Parent` property is set correctly, as is `ParentId`. When I inspect `item` in the debugger, however, `Parent` is null (however `ParentId` is still set correctly).

What would cause this particular instance to be different than the one the debugger got from evaluating `this.inner`? It's the same enumerable. If I call `this.inner.ToArray()` in the Watch window, it is also set correctly. It's just in this `foreach` loop that the property gets unset. Is this a bug worth documenting for Entity Framework?

Comment: To make this even more confusing, adding `.ToList()` onto my call to `WithIndices()` fixes the problem.

Comment: As a workaround, I explicitly included the navigation property in the initial query (`dataContext.Forums.Include( f => f.Parent )`), although from the reading I've done, self-referencing tables are supposed to automatically include their hierarchical navigation properties...